# Origin of the word "спасибi" for expressing gratitude

Tags: етимологія

Від чого походить слово "спасибі" (для вираження подяки)?

Comment: You probably wanted to ask: "What [words] does the word 'спасибі' come from?" (i.e. about **ancestors** of the word 'спасибі'). But instead you've asked: "What [words] come from the word 'спасибі'?" (i.e. about **descentants** of the word 'спасибі'). I.e. you should write: "Від чого походить слово 'спасибі' (для вираження подяки)?".

Comment: Да, now corrected.

Comment: BTW, it's considered more correct/literary to say _так_ (not _да_) for "yes" (_да_ in meaning "yes" is actually considered Russian). Still de-facto _да_ is also periodically used in colloquial speech (so, you will be understood anyway).

Comment: Так, now I understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both Ukrainian *спасибі* and Russian *спасибо* come from *спаси Бог*, which means "save [you] God" (*спаси* is an [imperative mood](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imperative_mood) for *спасати* "to save", *Бог* means "God"). After the centuries of usage these words got merged into single word, which got later shortened.

We also say *дякую* for expressing gratitude, which is a 1-st person form of the verb *дякувати* "to thank". I.e. we could say *я дякую тобі*, which literally means "I thank you", but we usually omit both *я* "I" (because it's implied when using 1-st person form of a verb) and "you" (because it's implied by context).

For references see:

- [O. Melnychuk, "Етимологічний словник української мови", volume 5, page 366](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom5.pdf#page=366);
- [M. Vasmer, "Russisches etymologisches Wörterbuch", "спасибо"](//vasmer.lexicography.online/%D1%81/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE);
- [English Wiktionary, "спасибо", "Etymology"](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE#Etymology);
- [Русский Викисловарь, "спасибо", "Этимология"](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F).